# Search specific text in all files

Tags: grep, centos, centos7

I need to find the files (and path to the files) on my CentOS 7 DirectAdmin server that contain the string "qunar". So it needs to search all files inside the server.

How can I achieve that?

I tried this, but then the server does not respond, is that because of the heaviness of the search?

```
grep -i -R "qunar" /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make grep print just the filenames instead of the lines containing a match, you can use the `-l` option:

```
grep -ril 'qunar' /
```

`-r` or `-R` is just a matter of taste.

As for "does not respond": you're searching the complete contents of every single file on the machine; depending on how common your search term is, you might have to wait for a while until the first hit.